# Execute shell command from C environment and redirect output

Tags: c, shell, unix

I have seen there are some questions about this topic, but none of the answers satisfied me. Here is the problem: I need to write two sockets (client and server), with the client having to send to the server an awk program with some lines of input. No problem in sending strings back and forth between the sockets. Supposing I have stored the program in a string `command` and the string I should pass to it in `input`, I have tried this:

```
execl("/usr/bin/awk", command, input, (char *)0);
```

And this works, the awk program runs and it writes on the server's stdout and stderr. Thing is, if there are lines with errors, I need to send these back to the client, which is pretty impossible since `execl` doesn't give me the chance to store its output in arrays. So, does anybody know a way to do this without using `system` and `popen`?

Comment: How do you pass back the stdout from the awk command to the client?

Comment: You need to pass a sensible `argv[0]` to `awk` — not the script that you want it to run.   For example: `execl("/usr/bin/awk", "awk", command, input, (char *)0);`.

Comment: I can't pass the stdout back - that's almost my problem. Awk's output goes immediately to files linked with my server's stdout, I don't have the chance to handle them.
Thank you about that Jonathan, I fixed it (but it wasn't that causing the problem).

Comment: Errors from the script will be written to its standard error.  The onus is on you to make sure that the standard error goes where you want it to go — somewhere that will be useful to you, that you can arrange to read and relay to the client.  There are many ways of doing that.  A simple one is to make the standard error refer to the same file descriptor as standard output.  The difficulty then is distinguishing error output from non-error (regular — standard) output.  Or you can open a pipe to read, or a socket, or …

Comment: And you sort out the child process's plumbing (files) between the `fork()` and the `execl()`.  That's when you decide where its standard output and standard error will go, and where its standard input will come from.

Comment: You'll need three pipes, one for each of the standard I/O streams. In the forked child process that execs the awk , you'll need to arrange for one end of each pipe to be connected to the standard I/O file descriptors 0 (standard input), 1 (standard output) and 2 (standard error output) before you exec the awk program. The other ends of these pipes will be accessible by the parent process. You can use `dup2` to change the file descriptors at the child end of the pipes.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it, using a pipe or fork could be a solution. But what about running awk? Do you know any ideas better than execl, maybe something more versatile?

Comment: @IanAbbott super! Is it possible to connect one end of a pipe to a pointer, for instance?

Comment: @DanieleBaieri, `exec`ing yourself is the *most versatile* thing there is -- because you need to do the plumbing yourself, you have full and complete control to how that plumbing is done.

Comment: @DanieleBaieri, ..,.no, you can't "pipe one end to a pointer", but you can have code in the parent process read from the FIFO and put content into a buffer it maintains a pointer to.

Comment: Okay, thank you all, super helpful. I'll go finish it.

Comment: If you need to send only stderr, the easiest way by far is to use `popen ("command arguments 2>&1 1>/dev/null", "r")`.

Comment: @DanieleBaieri I'm not sure what you mean by "connect one end of a pipe to a pointer", but you can use `fdopen` to connect a `int` file descriptor to a new `FILE *` stream.

Comment: I know, sorry, I'm still learning this kind of programming. I meant making the child process send its output to a string buffer instead of a file.